# Word lexical families

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am given a set of N words, and an integer K. 2 words are in the same group if they have exactly the first k letters and the last k letters identical. If they have more than k letters identical or less than k letters identical then the words are not in the same group. For example:
For k=3.

"abcdefg" and "abczefg" are in the same group
"abcddefg" and "abcdzefg" are not in the same group (the first k+1 letters are identical)
"abc" and "abc" are in the same group

A word can be in more than 1 groups. For example (k=3):
"abczefg" and "abcefg" form a group
"abczaefg" and "abcefg" form a group
"abczaefg" and "abczefg" are not in the same group (the first k+1 letters are identical)

The problem asks me to find the number of groups which contain the maximum number of words.

I thought about using a Trie (or Prefix Tree) and I assume this is the right data structure for this problem but I don't know how can I adapt them for this problem, because the part where if 2 words have more than k letters identical are not in the same group confuse me. My ideea has the complexity O(N*N*K) and considering that N<=10,000 and K<=100 I don't think that this ideea is fast enough. I would like to explain you my ideea, but it is not cleary yet even for me and I don't even know if it is correct, so I will skip this part.

My question is if there is a way I could solve this problem using a faster algorithm, and if there is such algorithm, I kindly ask you to explain it a little bit. Thank you in advance and I am sorry for the gramatical mistakes and if I didn't explain the problem clearly!

Answer (score 1):

First group all the words that share the first k letters and last k letters. Your largest group must sit inside one of these groups, since there's no way two words that differ at their starts and ends can be in the same solution.

So, within each of these groups (of words that share the same k letters at their start and end), you need to find a maximal set of words such that no two share the k+1'th letter, nor the k+1'th letter from the end.

Construct a graph where vertices are the pairs of letters that are (k+1) from each end (de-duping) from words in one of these groups, and edges occur between (a, b) and (c, d) if a=c or b=d.

You need to find a subgraph of this which has no edges in it. This reduced problem is an instance of the "maximum independent subgraph" problem, which is NP-hard, so you'll need to solve it by using a search and hoping the set of words you're given isn't too nasty. Perhaps there's something about the graphs here to give a faster solution, but I don't see it.

The solution to the entire problem is the largest solution to one of the reduced problems described above.

Hope this helps!